# How to use a constructor variable in the operator() function?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to call a variable which is declared in the constructor in the `operator()` function. Variable is declared of type `boost::multi_array<float, 2>`. But still it throws the error:

> error: no match for ‘operator /’

I guess boost library has these predefined operators! Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```cpp
#ifndef CORRELATOR_CHARACTERISTIC_FUNCTION_HPP
#define CORRELATOR_CHARACTERISTIC_FUNCTION_HPP

#include <halmd/numeric/blas/fixed_vector.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include "read_box.hpp"

namespace correlator {

class Characteristic_function
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::multi_array<float, 2>> sample_type;
    typedef halmd::fixed_vector<double, 3> result_type;
    using k_type = boost::multi_array<float, 2>;

    Characteristic_function()
    {
        // using array_2d_t = boost::multi_array<float, 2>;
        read_box read_box_file;
        // auto b = read_box_file.open_dataset("file.h5");
        
        k_type frame_b = read_box_file.read_frame(1);
        auto w = frame_b[0][0];
    }
       
    result_type operator()(sample_type const &first, sample_type const &second) const 
    {
        result_type c_func = 0;
        size_t N = first->size();
        N = std::min(100UL, N);
        Characteristic_function w;
        //  k_type Characteristic_function wave;
        // std::cout << "First wave vector: " << wave[0][1] << std::endl;                
        double k = 2 * M_PI/w;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= 0; ++j) {
                double dr = (*first)[i][j] - (*second)[i][j];
                c_func[j] = exp(k*dr);
            }
        } 
        
        return c_func / static_cast<double>(N);
    }
};
}
#endif /* ! CORRELATOR_CHARACTERISTIC_FUNCTION_HPP */
```

`w` just a float number and I want to use this number in the `operator()` function.

Comment: Please show a [mre] including the full error message from the compiler

Comment: The only variable of type `boost::multi_array` is `frame_b` and you do neither call it, nor do you apply `/` to it. `w` in `operator()` is not a float, it is declared to be of type `Characteristic_function`. I do not understand the question. If you want to use the `w` from the constructor in the `operator()`, then you need to store it in a data member.

Comment: @user17732522 `w = frame_b[0][0]` is declared in the constructor. In simple words, I need `w` in the declaration of `k` in the `operator()` function.

Comment: @Rohit ok, then just store it as a data member of the class

Comment: @user17732522 Can you show me with an example how to do that? Sorry! I'm pretty new to C++

Comment: Instead of trying to divide by an array try getting its inverse and multiplying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```cpp
/* Characteristic function */

#ifndef CORRELATOR_CHARACTERISTIC_FUNCTION_HPP
#define CORRELATOR_CHARACTERISTIC_FUNCTION_HPP

#include <halmd/numeric/blas/fixed_vector.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <complex>
#include "read_box.hpp"

namespace correlator {

class Characteristic_function
{
private:
    double w;
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::multi_array<float, 2>> sample_type;
    typedef halmd::fixed_vector<double, 3> result_type;
    // using k_type = boost::multi_array<float, 2>;
    typedef boost::multi_array<float, 2> k_type;

    Characteristic_function()
    {
        read_box read_box_file;
        
        k_type frame_b = read_box_file.read_frame(1);
        w = frame_b[0][0];
    }

    result_type operator()(sample_type const &first, sample_type const &second) const 
    {
        result_type c_func = 0;
        size_t N = first->size();
        N = std::min(100000UL, N);
                        
        double k = 2 * M_PI / w;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= 0; ++j) {
                double dr = exp( k*((*first)[i][j] - (*second)[i][j]) );
                c_func[j] = dr;
            }
        } 
        
        return c_func / static_cast<double>(N);
    }
};
}
#endif /* ! CORRELATOR_CHARACTERISTIC_FUNCTION_HPP */
```

It will automatically reads the value of `w`.